# problem with kafka client when broker is down

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am seeing this exception in my kafka client when the broker is down:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: KafkaConsumer is not safe for multi-threaded access
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.acquire(KafkaConsumer.java:2452)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.acquireAndEnsureOpen(KafkaConsumer.java:2436)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1217)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1210)
    at com.actimize.infrastructure.config.KafkaAlertsDistributor$1.run(KafkaAlertsDistributor.java:71)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The problem is, I am not running a multi-threaded application. I am running an hello-world example with single thread and wanted to see how it behaves when the broker is down (because I want to start the broker later in unit tests).

Here's my code, give or take:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
executor.execute (createRunnable());
...
// in the runnable's run method
Properties props = // create props
consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("test-topic"));
while (true) {
    ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = null;
    try {
        System.out.println("going to poll");
        records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(1));
        System.out.println("finished polling, got " + records.count() + " records");
    } catch (WakeupException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        continue;
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
        Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put("partition", record.partition());
        data.put("offset", record.offset());
        data.put("value", record.value());
        System.out.println("consumer got: " + data);
    }
}
```

When the broker is down, the poll() method works fine for the first 4 or 5 times. It returns zero records and it prints a warning to the log. By the 5th or 6th time it starts outputing this error.

Here is a full log. It shows that are two threads (pool-3 and pool-4) doing some work behind the scene, I am not sure why this is happening, it's not coming from my code.

```
2021-02-21 12:16:00,057 INFO  [pool-3-thread-1] config.KafkaConsumerSample$1 (KafkaConsumerSample.java:68) - going to poll
2021-02-21 12:16:00,404 WARN  [pool-3-thread-1] clients.NetworkClient (NetworkClient.java:757) - [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumer-tutorial-1, groupId=consumer-tutorial] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2021-02-21 12:16:00,404 WARN  [pool-3-thread-1] clients.NetworkClient$DefaultMetadataUpdater (NetworkClient.java:1033) - [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumer-tutorial-1, groupId=consumer-tutorial] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2021-02-21 12:16:01,057 INFO  [pool-3-thread-1] config.KafkaConsumerSample$1 (KafkaConsumerSample.java:70) - finished polling, got 0 records
2021-02-21 12:16:01,057 INFO  [pool-3-thread-1] config.KafkaConsumerSample$1 (KafkaConsumerSample.java:68) - going to poll
2021-02-21 12:16:02,057 INFO  [pool-3-thread-1] config.KafkaConsumerSample$1 (KafkaConsumerSample.java:70) - finished polling, got 0 records
2021-02-21 12:16:02,057 INFO  [pool-3-thread-1] config.KafkaConsumerSample$1 (KafkaConsumerSample.java:68) - going to poll
2021-02-21 12:16:02,427 INFO  [pool-4-thread-1] config.KafkaConsumerSample$1 (KafkaConsumerSample.java:68) - going to poll
2021-02-21 12:16:02,923 WARN  [pool-3-thread-1] clients.NetworkClient (NetworkClient.java:757) - [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumer-tutorial-1, groupId=consumer-tutorial] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2021-02-21 12:16:02,924 WARN  [pool-3-thread-1] clients.NetworkClient$DefaultMetadataUpdater (NetworkClient.java:1033) - [Consumer clientId=consumer-consumer-tutorial-1, groupId=consumer-tutorial] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2021-02-21 12:16:03,058 INFO  [pool-3-thread-1] config.KafkaConsumerSample$1 (KafkaConsumerSample.java:70) - finished polling, got 0 records
2021-02-21 12:16:03,058 INFO  [pool-3-thread-1] config.KafkaConsumerSample$1 (KafkaConsumerSample.java:68) - going to poll
2021-02-21 12:16:03,061 INFO  [pool-3-thread-1] config.KafkaConsumerSample$1 (KafkaConsumerSample.java:75) - error
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: KafkaConsumer is not safe for multi-threaded access
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.acquire(KafkaConsumer.java:2452)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.acquireAndEnsureOpen(KafkaConsumer.java:2436)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1217)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1210)
    at com.actimize.infrastructure.config.KafkaConsumerSample$1.run(KafkaConsumerSample.java:69)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Exception in thread "pool-3-thread-1" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: KafkaConsumer is not safe for multi-threaded access
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.acquire(KafkaConsumer.java:2452)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.close(KafkaConsumer.java:2335)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.close(KafkaConsumer.java:2290)
    at com.actimize.infrastructure.config.KafkaConsumerSample$1.run(KafkaConsumerSample.java:88)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2021-02-21 12:16:03,429 INFO  [pool-4-thread-1] config.KafkaConsumerSample$1 (KafkaConsumerSample.java:70) - finished polling, got 0 records
2021-02-21 12:16:03,429 INFO  [pool-4-thread-1] config.KafkaConsumerSample$1 (KafkaConsumerSample.java:68) - going to poll
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the logs you've shared, two thread starting to poll almost at the same time:

```sh
2021-02-21 12:16:02,057 INFO  [pool-3-thread-1] config.KafkaConsumerSample$1 (KafkaConsumerSample.java:68) - going to poll
2021-02-21 12:16:02,427 INFO  [pool-4-thread-1] config.KafkaConsumerSample$1 (KafkaConsumerSample.java:68) - going to poll
```

There are extra measurements to be taken into consideration in order to implement multithreaded consumer.

The most important points that you may want to tackle are:

- Ensure that records from the same partitions are processed only by one thread at a time
- Commit offsets only after records are processed
- Handle group rebalancing properly

Further reading: [Kafka Consumer Multi Threaded Messaging](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-consumer-multi-threaded-messaging/)

Comment: Unfortunately this was an error in my code, I was accessing the consumer in two threads without realizing it. I thought I was using a single thread.